# Почему explode(" ", $string ) разбивает строку с пробелом "строка " на 2 элемента?

Tags: php

Почему `explode(" ", $string )` разбивает строку с пробелом "строка " на 2 элемента? И последний элемент пустой.

Comment: В чём, собственно, проблема? Почему вы считаете должно быть иначе?

Comment: Интересно понять, почему массив разбивается именно на 2 элемента с пустым последним, а не на 1, как если бы в конце пробела не было а просто была бы "строка"

Comment: А почему должно разбиваться на один? Где в документации такое поведение описано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что можно вычитать отсюда [PHP Explode](http://www.php.su/explode())

> Если separator - пустая строка (""), explode() возвращает FALSE. Если separator не содержится в string, то explode() возвращает массив, содержащий один элемент string.

Собстна explode разбивает строку на 2 элемента потому, что разделитель всё же содержится в строке.